# Angular 2 can't render data from API call

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 2 and having trouble rendering data from an api call into my template. Ill post a short example of my component and template.

**TS file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalDirective } from '../../../global.directive';

export class MainInfoComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public globalDirective: GlobalDirective) {}

 logURL() {
     //returns undefined
     console.log(this.globalDirective.bgURL);

 }

 ngOnInit() {
     this.logURL();
 }
}
```

this.globalDirective.bgURL is a string of an img url, we'll say http://www.example.com/myImg.png

The GlobalDirective file makes a call to a JSON file sitting on S3 and returns img links and other things I am trying to render in the template. I know the correct data is being returned because I can see it in the console.

**Template**

```
<p>{{globalDirective.bgURL}}</p>   <!--  This works  -->
<header [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + globalDirective.bgURL + ')'}">  <!-- Returns undefined  -->
```

I am trying to figure out why I can render `globalDirective.bgURL` within the P tags, but if I try to render it as a header style or log it in ngOnInit it returns undefined.

I think the issue may be something to do with the async nature of the JSON request. If i set a string equal to the url I want, and then specify that in the template it works fine.

**TS file**

```
bgURL: string = 'http://www.example.com/myImg.png';
```

**Template**

```
<!-- This works -->
<header [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + bgURL + ')'}">
```

Thanks in advance for any help, been beating my head against this one for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

```
<header [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + globalDirective.bgURL + ')'} ">
```

Comment: whoops.  yea I think I tried that when working through this. Ill make sure and go back and edit my original question. I am still confused as to why my logURL() function returns undefined.